# Need to capture user pk who is posting a tweet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

The problem I'm having is somewhere between my views.py and serializers.py, To start this is the error I'm getting. It happens when I try and create a new tweet. The parameter it is having an issue with is from the views `TweetAPIView: perform_create`.

The TweetSerializers doesn't have a 'user' field but I've also tried setting `author=self.request.user`

The goal is to have this new tweet being posted attached to the user posting it.

FYI building basic Twitter functionality with this project.

> Tweet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, mixins

from .models import Tweet, User
from .serializers import TweetSerializer
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly



class TweetAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
    return Tweet.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',
                          max_length=255, unique=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email

class Tweet(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tweets")
    tweet_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_text
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'password',
              'first_name', 'last_name')


class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'author',
            'tweet_text',
            'created_on'
        ]
```

Comment: You said you tried `serializer.save(author=self.request.user)`. What happened then? It can't have given the same error...

Comment: Also you don't need to inherit from `mixins.CreateModelMixin`: The `CreateAPIView` already inherits from this mixin.

Comment: Finally your serializer (`TweetSerializer`) should only contain the fields that are submitted via POST. It won't validate right now, because it doesn't receive an author when it's created and validated. You only pass it to the serializer after it was found valid (`perform_create()` is called only if the serializer is valid). Or mark the fields `pk`, `author` and `created_on` as read-only (if you use the same serializer to `GET` a `Tweet`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit user and make it author since thats what you call the user in your models.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
   serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```